# Leaflet Control Gecoder - Exception: "Nominatim is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet

i have some really issue to use the leaflet Control Gecoder plugin for leaflet maps ([leaflet-control-geocoder](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder)), i must be a very idiot because i just try to replicate the same example i found on this page [demo-plugin](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-control-geocoder/).
The issue is when i try to intialize the control, i have the exception "this 'GeoCoder' is not a constructor". Here the code of the example:

```
//Set leaflet Map, with markercluster and other basic functionality
//Set variables
var geoCoderGoogle,geoCoderControl;
var btn,selection,marker,selector;
var geocoders = {
    'Nominatim': L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
    'Bing': L.Control.Geocoder.bing(bingAPIKey),
    'Mapbox': L.Control.Geocoder.mapbox(mapBoxAPIKey),
    'Google': L.Control.Geocoder.google(googleAPIKey),
    'Photon': L.Control.Geocoder.photon()
};
//Set geocoders on ready of the document
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    //Init the leafletMap if  is not setted
    //invoke the geocoder plugin on the leaflet map
    addPluginGeoCoder();
    //implement select of the geocoder.
    for (var name in geocoders) {
        btn = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'leaflet-bar', selector);
        btn.innerHTML = name;
        (function(n) {
            L.DomEvent.addListener(btn, 'click', function() {
                select(geocoders[n], this);
            }, btn);
        })(name);
        if (!selection) select(geocoders[name], btn);
    }


});

function select(geocoder, el) {
    if (selection) L.DomUtil.removeClass(selection, 'selected');
    geoCoderControl.options.geocoder = geocoder;
    L.DomUtil.addClass(el, 'selected');
    selection = el;
}

//Now add the control for the Geocoder with a function
function addPluginGeoCoder() {
    alert("Compile addPluginGeoCoder...");
    try {
        if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(geoCoderControl)) {
            alert("1");
            selector = L.DomUtil.get('geocode-selector');
            alert("2")
            geoCoderControl = new L.Control.Geocoder({ geocoder: null });
            alert("3")
            geoCoderControl.addTo(map);
            alert("4")
        } else {
            map.addControl(geoCoderControl);
        }
        alert("...compiled addPluginGeoCoder");
    }catch(e){
        alert("Exception:addPluginGeoCoder->"+e.message);
    }
}
```

Now when i run this piece of code i have these alerts: '1','2',**'Exception:addPluginGeoCoder-> Nominatim is not a constructor'**.
Even if i remove the Nominatim Geocoder from the list of 'geocoders' i have the same issue.

My final objective anyway is use the leaflet GeoCoder plugin with the google api and convert a address in coordinates, get the coordinates and save them in a array for more uses. So after setted the GeoCoderController, probably i invoke a function like this:

```
function saveInfo(){ 
 geoCoderControl.options.geocoder.geocode(address, function(results) {
                var latLng= new L.LatLng(results[0].center.lat, results[0].center.lng);
                marker = new L.Marker (latLng);
                map.addlayer(marker);
                addressVar = address;
                otherVar = result.html;
                alert("add marker:" + result.name + "," + result.center.lat + "," + result.center.lng + "," + otherVar);
                array.push(result.name, otherVar, result.center.lat, result.center.lng,addressVar);
            });
}
```

Any help is welcome.

**UPDATE:** I have created the same issue in a jsfiddle example: [link example](http://jsfiddle.net/4535992/5qLdhfnh/3/).

The Firefox browser say: "Nominatim is not a constructor".
The Internet Explorer say: "Object doesn't support this action".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, I'm guessing you're using an old version, the problem you're seeing was fixed here: https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder/commit/423610e7f63fd381357f44b2bc9853bd919c3e88

Upgrade to 1.3.1, and this should be fixed, as far as I can tell.

BTW: you should really look into using Developer Tools in Chrome, it's tremendously more powerful than debugging through `alert`s.

Comment: In fact it works with version 1.3.1, Can i suggest in your README file of the github project, the download link "Download latest release" to link to the version 1.3.1?
anyway , Thanks so much for this plugin.